# Looking for Hosted Subversion and Visual Studio plug in combo

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, visualsvn

Can anyone recommend a proven combination of a hosted Subversion solution and supported Visual Studio plug-in?  I like what wush.net offers as far as a service, and I like VisualSVN as an IDE plug-in, but it doesn't look like wush.net supports access via VisualSVN / TortoiseSVN.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Wush.NET works great with TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wush.NET](http://wush.net/corpsite/landing) works fantastic with both [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) (Explorer) and [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) (Visual Studio).  I have been very happy with this combo.

They're basically just providing a very clean, simple Subversion access (+Trac), so any standard SVN client should work fine.

Comment: Thank you much!  Going to head in that direction right now.

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that TortoiseSVN was just a GUI that wrappered the same interface that the commandline uses.  I would think if it works with the commandline, it should work with Tortoise as well.  Not 100% sure on that though.

Comment: That is the case.  It works great on Wush.NET (and should work on any other SVN provider, as well)

Comment: Yeah, I was a little confused on exactly that, but it looks like Reed has confident experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access a repository hosted at wush.net with any Subversion client.  They all use the same repository access libraries anyway.  TortoiseSVN supports HTTP, HTTPS, SVN, and SVN+SSH for remote repository access.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) in the past and enjoyed the experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Indefero](http://www.indefero.net), with it you also have webdav access to your subversion repository. This is working really well with people not knowing subversion.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using [SpringLoops](http://www.springloops.com) successfully for over a year now. Our Subversion clients are TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN. I am sure VisualSVN will work as well but I have not tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I thought I'd add another item for others looking for the same info.

I've just started using [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) & VisualSVN - 3 weeks in it's been hassle free and that's just on the free account.