# SVN in .NET for a small project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, svn, project

I manage a small project for a client I want to be able to start using SVN to give a better service from multiple computers, I would like a SAAS solution as the project is to small to ask for a dedicated server in my client's company.

What is the best SVN hosting service/VS2010 plugin you recommend

Thank you

PS. Other ideas for a solution of my problem are welcome I am new to this way of working (SVN)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is a good, free and popular plugin.  I use it all the time with VS2010, and I'm very happy with it.  I also use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) outside of Visual Studio.

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com) is also very popular.

Subversion hosting can be found from many hosting providers, either seperately or as past of a web hosting package.  Check out these similar questions:

- [Looking for Hosted Subversion and Visual Studio plug in combo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228804/looking-for-hosted-subversion-and-visual-studio-plug-in-combo)
- [Hosted subversion recommendations or suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299990/hosted-subversion-recommendations-or-suggestions)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297153/can-you-recommend-a-svn-closed-source-project-hosting-site

Answer (score 4):

I use the [Agent SVN](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/) plug-in with the Subversion file protocol repository and I works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com) and been very happy with it, or at least as happy as any Subversion user can expect to be. It builds on top of the TortoiseSVN explorer plugin, and does support more advanced stuff like dragging files around inside Visual Studio.

That said, I'd strongly advise you to consider Git or Mercurial instead of Subversion. They don't as easily mess up your local workspace, allow you to commit partial work without interfering with everybody else, and easier sharing through repository cloning and greatly improved merging of changes. If this sounds interesting I'd recommend bitbucket or GitHub as good online source control providers.

Tool support for Visual Studio is almost as good as for Subversion and have a lot more momentum so I'd expect them to catch up pretty soon.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Codesion](http://codesion.com/) from CollabNet as hosting service, and [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) (open source) as Visual Studio plugin. Although I prefer to use TortoiseSVN as svn client, even if it not integrated to Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there a reason to use SVN outside VS2010, can it conflict if I update outside of VS?

Comment: I use TortoiseSVN outside VS2010 because you've got a general purpose client that way. You can use it then for your java projects, or what have you, rather than just your .NET project that you're working on in VS.

Comment: @David In my case, I have many files that do not really belong to the VS project and I want them versioned as well. As far as I know, with AnkhSVN you can only version the files you have explicitly included in your project/solution.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use http://www.projectlocker.com/ for SVN hosting. Its free for small projects, easy to set up, and has always worked well for me. I believe it also allows 3 users and 3 active projects, as opposed to 1 of each like a lot of other free hosts.

I've used http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ in the past because in integrates with VS2010, but lately I've switched to explorer integration with http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

No reason why really, just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/). It's free private hosting for small teams. And [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)  as VS plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

The *TortoiseSVN* works well for me.